# API call to directory.members.list failed with error: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: google-apps-script

****Edited 3/13/2020*****

Hi guys, this is the full function:

```
function AddNewMember(LastEntryMail)
{
    var NewMember = 
        {
         email: LastEntryMail,  
         role: 'MEMBER'
        };
    var MemberExist = false;
    var pageToken, page;
    var groupEmail = 'members@mydomain.com';
    var groupDomainName = 'mydomain.com';

    do 
    {
        page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail,{
        domain: groupDomainName,
        orderBy: 'Email',
        maxResults: 1000,
        pageToken: pageToken
        });
      var GroupMembers = page.members;
      for (var m in GroupMembers) 
      {
        var email = GroupMembers[m].email;
        if(email.toLowerCase() == LastEntryMail)     
        {
          MemberExist = true;
          break; //stop the for loop
        }
      }
      if(MemberExist == true)
      {
       break; //stop the do loop
      }
      else //new member email was not found in current page members list. go to next page
      {
       pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
      }
    } while (pageToken && !MemberExist);

    if(MemberExist == false)
    {
       try
       {
        AdminDirectory.Members.insert(NewMember, groupEmail);
        Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', LastEntryMail, groupEmail);
        var AddNewMember = 'MemberAddedToGroup';
       }
       catch(e)
       {
         Logger.log(LastEntryMail+"has invoked an error"+groupEmail);  
       }
    }
  }
```

Thing is, it is also not reproducing on my end. I haven't changed a thing in the code or in the project settings.
could it be a tweak on the google server?
Thanks

******End Update 03/13/2020*********************

I have a function for adding new members to my group. bellow is the part where I'm reading the list from the domain:

```
 page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail,{
        domain: groupDomainName,
        orderBy: 'Email',
        maxResults: 1000,
        pageToken: pageToken
        });
      var GroupMembers = page.members;
```

Problem is, every time I run the function, I get:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.members.list failed with error: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

I have turned on the **Admin Directory API** under the project **Advanced Google Services**
I also checked in the AppScript Console under Project OAuth Scopes that I have the correct scope URL:
**https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group**

I have the same exact function running under another one of my projects, with the same access permissions and it runs OK.

What am I missing? thanks

Comment: Hello @Assaf, is your script associated with any cloud projects? Moreover, are you able to obtain the desired result by using [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? Cheers!

Comment: Hi ale13,thank you for reaching out.if I understand, playground is when you need to access from a web page. Im running the script from within google domain. further more, as I mentioned, under the same domain, I have two projects running the exact function. I copied the working function to a new project and set the same permissions....

Comment: Hi there @Assaf! I am studying your issue, but I am not able to reproduce it. Could you please share the smallest code that develops the undesired behaviour? And please, tell us all what you are trying to accomplish with this action.

Comment: Could it be that you created the scope with another api call? If so, have you deleted it to generate a new one with the `admin.directory.group`?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for taking the time. I have edited the post with regard to your comments